# extract words before optional parentheses and inside parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of strings that look like the following two sentences:

```
A couple of words (abbreviation)
A couple of words
```

I am trying to get python to extract the 'a couple of words' part and the 'abbreviation' part with a single regex, while also allowing strings where no abbreviation is given.

I've come up with this:

```
re_both = re.compile(r"^(.*)(?:\((.*)\))$")
```

It works for the first case, but not for the second case:

```
[in]   re_both.findall('a couple of words (abbreviation)')
[out]  [('a couple of words ', 'abbreviation')]

[in]   re_both.findall('a couple of words')
[out]  []
```

I would like the second case to yield:

```
[out] [('a couple of words','')]
```

Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine except you have to make the second part optional and make the first part non greedy.:

```
re_both = re.compile(r"^(.*?)(?:\((.*)\))?$")
#                   here __^      here __^
```

Comment: I already tried that, but that gives a wrong result for the first case:

    [('a couple of words (abbreviation)', '')]

Comment: The non-greedy match '?' in the first capturing group suggested by @Avinash Raj did it.

Comment: @jkokorian: Sorry I wasn't focused on that, but, sure, make the first group non greedy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the second part as optional by adding a quantifier `?`, and also you need to add the quantifer `?` inside the first capturing group just after to `.*` so that it would do a non-greedy match.

```
^(.*?)(?:\((.*)\))?$
    ^             ^
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kB8pY9/8)

If you don't want to capture the space which was just before to the `(` by the first capturing group then you could try the below regex,

```
^(.*?)(?: \((.*)\))?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kB8pY9/9)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """A couple of words (abbreviation)
... A couple of words"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'^(.*?)(?: \((.*)\))?$', s, re.M)
>>> m
[('A couple of words', 'abbreviation'), ('A couple of words', '')]
>>> m = re.findall(r'^(.*?)(?:\((.*)\))?$', s, re.M)
>>> m
[('A couple of words ', 'abbreviation'), ('A couple of words', '')]
```